# Manually encrypt data with OpenSSL with Qt

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

I know that Qt has SSL/TLS support to TCP communications, and I wanted to leverage the cross-platform high-level API to encrypt communications not based on TCP. If possibly keeping Diffie–Hellman protocol to establish the secured communication.

Now I've been looking at the classes sources, and [where data is encrypted](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp.html#619) for instance, and it appears to be all private and not easily reusable.

- Is there an easy way to use what was developed by Qt for something else than TCP, at least for simple encryption? full SSL support?
- I guess you can always open a local TCP port, and build a TCP-to-Other local proxy, but that looks a bit silly, just to be able to reuse Qt implementation.

I found the [Hacking on Qt SSL Support](https://wiki.qt.io/Hacking_on_Qt%27s_SSL_Support) in the Wiki, which gives some perspective but not exactly how to leverage existing implementation.